# What is more efficient SQL statement than the one shown

Tags: sql, where-clause, case-insensitive

What problems does the statement shown here present? What could be changed that would allow a more efficient statement than this one? I was asked in an interview.

```
SELECT
    DATE, location, USER_ID
FROM
    customers
WHERE
    UPPER(name) = 'SATISH';
```

Comment: Add an index on `name`, maybe?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: as long as you use `UPPER(name)`, and index won't really help ....

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? SQL is only a query language, not the name of database product.

Comment: @marc_s: yeah, I suspected that. But that was my best idea :)

Comment: i think the problem is using variable directly in codeT it's better declaring a variable, pass value to it, and finally use it to prevent hacking or etc

Comment: I think they are using Oracle. As per my knowledge SQL Server is case insensitive.

Comment: SQL Server's case sensitivity depends on the **collation** you're using for your database/table. It *can be* case insensitive - or it can be case sensitve - your choice

Answer (score 2):

This is your query:

```
SELECT DATE, location, USER_ID
FROM customers
WHERE UPPER(name) = 'SATISH';
```

Making this query more efficient is basically about using indexes.

First, many databases are by default case-insensitive.  So this query could be equivalent to:

```
WHERE name = 'SATISH'
```

This version, however, can take advantage of an index on `users(name)`.  Even a case-insensitive collation will probably not use an index with the `UPPER()` function.

If your database is case-sensitive, three options come to mind:

1. Store the name as upper case.
2. Use a function-based index.
3. Use a generated column instead of the base column

Not all databases support all three methods.

You can enforce the first with a `check` constraint:

```
check chk_user_name_uppercase (name = upper(name));
```

You can implement the second in some databases as:

```
create index idx_user_uname on user(upper(name));
```

You can implement the third as:

```
alter table user add name_upper as (upper(name));

create index idx_user_name_upper on user(name_upper);
```

Then the `where` clause would look like:

```
where name_upper = 'SATISH'
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you use a function on the column, an index on name would probably not been used. Many DB-System support case-insensitive indexes/search anyway, so the upper is not needed.

In other cases it could be useful to store the name in uppercase(maybe an extra column). Then the upper on the search-value is needed, too.